# @ViewScoped JSF managed bean reconstructed on postbacks

Tags: jsf, view-scope

I'm using JSF 2 (Mojarra 2.2.11) with WildFly9.0.1.

I have 3 `selectOneMenu`s as seen below. The ajax events work fine loading data to the next one using `omnifaces converter`.

Problem: even if the third "Header" `selectOneMenu` is populated, on `h:commandButton` action I can't get the Header Object giving a Null in the backing bean.

I'm able to get the Module Object calling `saveNewHeader` method but `saveNewQuestion` crashes when I'm trying to access the Header Object.

From the reference: [Retrieving the value of the selected item in a SelectOneMenu List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130559/retrieving-the-value-of-the-selected-item-in-a-selectonemenu-list), I am suspecting a queue processing issue of JSF?

How can I solve/manage it? Thank you for your time.

Console:

```
12:37:17,583 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=#{questionBean.saveNewQuestion(questionBean.header)}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns=...> 

<h:head></h:head> 

<h:body>

<h:form id="frmQuestion" > 

<h4>Add Question to Header</h4>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel  value="ProductType: " />

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{questionBean.productType}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{questionBean.productTypes}" var="productType" 
            itemValue="#{productType}" itemLabel="#{productType.type}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{questionBean.loadModules()}" render="moduleId2" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel  value="Module: " />

    <h:selectOneMenu id="moduleId2" value="#{questionBean.module}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{questionBean.modules}" var="module" 
            itemValue="#{module}" itemLabel="#{module.moduleName}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{questionBean.loadHeaders()}" render="headerId2" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel  value="Header Name: " />

        <h:selectOneMenu id="headerId2" value="#{questionBean.header}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{questionBean.headers}" var="header" 
                itemValue="#{header}" itemLabel="#{header.name}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>


</h:panelGrid>


<h:commandButton action="#{questionBean.saveNewQuestion(questionBean.header)}" value="Add New Question"  

/>



...
```

QuestionBean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class QuestionBean implements Serializable {

private List<Header> headers; // getter & setter
private Header header; // getter & setter

private List<Module> modules; // getter & setter
private Module module; // getter & setter


@PostConstruct
public void init(){

    this.productTypes = publicService.getAllproductTypes();

}

public void saveNewHeader(Module module)
{
    System.out.println(module.getModuleName()); // works fine
}

public void saveNewQuestion(Header header){

        System.out.println(header.getHeaderName()); // crashes here
}
```

**UPDATE** (after BalusC comment)

It looks like a the bean behaves like a `@RequestScoped`: how can this happen?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need parameters in these methods if you got access to them in backing bean? Is your `@ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.bean` package?

Comment: @Geinmachi: With or without specifying the parameter I can't access the Object or its properties in the backing bean. Yes my `@ViewScoped` is from `javax.faces.bean` (I've edited the bean).

Comment: Symptoms suggst bean is actually not view scoped and behaves like request scoped. Can you confirm this? (just debug/log the construction)

Comment: @BalusC: You are right Legend. I've edited my question. How can this happen? I defined it as a `@ViewScoped`

Comment: Any JARs in webapp's /WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @BalusC: Many: primefaces, richfaces, iText....

Comment: Make sure it doesn't contain server-provided JARs.

Comment: @BalusC: Do you recognize a server-provided one in the below List? annotations-4.0.0.Final.jar, 
com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar, 
commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar, 
commons-digester-1.7.jar, 
commons-logging-1.1.jar, 
commons.collections-3.2.1.jar, 
cssparser-0.9.16.jar, 
groovy-all-1.8.6.jar, 
guava-18.0.jar, 
humanity-1.0.10.jar, 
iText-2.1.7.jar, 
jasperreports-5.1.2.jar, 
omnifaces-2.2.jar, 
primefaces-5.3.jar, 
richfaces-a4j-4.5.8.Final.jar, 
richfaces-core-4.5.8.Final.jar, 
richfaces-page-fragments-4.5.8.Final.jar, 
richfaces-rich-4.5.8.Final.jar, 
sac-1.3.jar, 
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

Comment: Only validation-api. And, on an unrealated note, mysql should actually be moved to server (as it is normally the one responsible for managing the DB connection pool).

Comment: @BalusC: removed it. but no improvement. totally agree I'm generating japerreport with this connection.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you for trying to troubleshoot.